# Changing the color of non selected edges in the theme preferences

Tags: 3d-view, customization, theme

There is an option to change the color of various edges (selected, seam, crease...)in the themes menu, but not for the simple non selected edges. there is a way to change the black color?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the preferences you could change the *Wire Edit* color.

[image]

This influences the non selected edges in edit mode:

[image]